# Issue with include_path and open_basedir

Tags: php, iis, plesk, include-path, open-basedir

I have a subdomain called `ticket.domain.com`, and this is located at `C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\subdomains\ticket\httpdocs`...

In my Plesk settings, for the subdomain, I have specified the following settings:

```
include_path: 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\subdomains\ticket\httpdocs\'
open_basedir: 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\;C:\Windows\Temp\'
```

These settings are reflected in my `phpinfo()`!

However, when I try to include a local file within this directory I am receiving the `open_basedir restriction in effect...` error.

The local file is being included with the code `include('file.php')`.

I therefore believe that the `include_path` is being ignored as the script must be looking somewhere outside the `open_basedir`.

Can the `include_path` be set at runtime? In the past, I have found that Plesk offers settings that cannot actually be changed at runtime (on Windows).

Otherwise, what else could be the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried being more specific: `include './file.php';` or failing that explicitly state the full path on the file system: `include __dir__.'/file.php';` - out of curiosity what does: `echo __dir__;` give you?

Comment: Ben - did you ever get this solved?  I'm facing the same issue when trying to upload files to the server and it's driving me insane.

Comment: Hi Ben, 
did you ever get this solved? (2)